# Place divs on each other & sticky - should be scroll up when page scroll up & stack on bottom when page scroll down

Tags: html, css, sticky

I want to achieve this type of working functionality - https://creative-websites.co.uk/ -[Intro & Steps Section on the given link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfDe.png) how I can make this working with less div wrap structure. I have tried CSS sticky property but didn't get the same working demo.

Anyone could help here would be appreciated.

I have write this HTML code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="one" class="sticky">ONE</div>
    <div id="two" class="sticky">TWO TWO</div>
    <div id="three" class="sticky">THREE THREE THREE</div>
    <div id="four" class="sticky">FOUR FOUR FOUR FOUR</div>
</div>

CSS

.wrap{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 900vh;
}


.sticky {
  height: 50vh;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
#one {
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#two {
  top: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
#three {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#four {
  top: 120px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```